# Correct value but program still says it wrong

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to html and coding in general.Hope someone can help me,thank in advance.I want it to alarm if i put wrong value but even if i put correct value it still alarm me.Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#name").blur(function(){
        var value = this.value;
        if(isNaN(value)){
            alert("Wrong!Please enter your name again");
        }
    });
    $("#email").blur(function(){
        var value = this.value;
        if(isNaN(value)){
            alert("Wrong!Please enter your email again");
        }
    });
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        alert("Your message has been sent successfully!Thank you.")
    });
});
```

And my code in jetbrain:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
    <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name"    type="text" required>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
    <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required>
</div>
```

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: You might want to write in words what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: If you want to use `html5` with `javascript` when handling validation you can refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16069817/6

Comment: using isNaN to validate a field for name and email makes no sense. isNaN is for validating numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's on your isnan jquery function. Please don't use that kind of function when validating inputs like emails. Instead you should create a variable to test whether the inputs contain valid characters.

For example:

```
$('#email').blur(function() {
    var testEmail = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
    if (testEmail.test(this.value)) alert('passed');
    else alert('failed');
});
```

Comment: It works now,thank you so much.I am still new to this so can you explain more about this code :  var testEmail = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;? what is it for and how does it work?

Comment: It's a character to test whether your email is valid or not,

Answer (score 0):

isNaN = is not a number.

You are checking if the input is numeric.

You probably want something like this:

```
if ($('#name').is(':empty')){
   //do something
}
```

So in your case:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#name").blur(function(){
        if ($('#name').is(':empty')){
            alert("Wrong!Please enter your name again");
        }
    });
    $("#email").blur(function(){
        if ($('#email').is(':empty')){
            alert("Wrong!Please enter your email again");
        }
    });
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        alert("Your message has been sent successfully!Thank you.")
    });
}
```

Comment: It still say it is wrong although i put the correct type for the input
  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Pcz8j.png

Answer (score 0):

you just use those function in on submit because on blur not hold the submit process when user entred wrong value and try to submit it so that use like this.

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
        var pattern = /^\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$/i;

        if ($('#name').val()==''){

        alert("Wrong!Please enter your name");
        return false;
        }
        if ($('#email').val()=='' || !pattern.test($('#email').val())){

       alert("Wrong!Please enter Proper email");
        return false;
        }

    alert("Your message has been sent successfully!Thank you.")
});
```

Comment: I see.But if i type numeric in name box it will pass.Is there anyway to prevent that ?

Comment: add this or condition in above code     var name_pattern = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;                                                        if ($('#name').val()=='' || !name_pattern.test($('#name').val())){